# FreeBSD security log message: "Received data after socket was closed"

Tags: security, freebsd, tcp

I am running FreeBSD 7 and I get this in /var/log/security :

```
+++ /tmp/security.AIKARuA1  2009-06-30 03:05:17.000000000 +0500
+TCP: [69.147.83.36]:80 to [115.186.130.56]:50488 tcpflags 0x10<ACK>; tcp_do_segment: FIN_WAIT_1: Received 1440 bytes of data after socket was closed, sending RST and removing tcpcb
+TCP: [69.147.83.36]:80 to [115.186.130.56]:55740 tcpflags 0x10<ACK>; tcp_do_segment: FIN_WAIT_1: Received 1440 bytes of data after socket was closed, sending RST and removing tcpcb
+TCP: [69.147.83.33]:80 to [115.186.130.56]:52461 tcpflags 0x10<ACK>; tcp_do_segment: FIN_WAIT_1: Received 1440 bytes of data after socket was closed, sending RST and removing tcpcb
+TCP: [69.147.83.36]:80 to [115.186.130.56]:57401 tcpflags 0x10<ACK>; tcp_do_segment: FIN_WAIT_1: Received 1440 bytes of data after socket was closed, sending RST and removing tcpcb
```

What I can infer from here, which is quite obvious, is that client sent some data while the connection was supposed to be closed.
Could this be a case where I initiated an ssh session, got had a Man-in-the-Middle soemwhere without me knowing, and after I closed the SSH session he tried to connect again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen in cases where one side does an RST not a proper close, and if there's enough latency data can be in-flight for a while afterwards, or even due to queueing after both sides have closed.

In short, data *after* close is fairly innocuous as the session had to be up in the first place to cause that, so don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source address: **[69.147.83.36]:80**. Notice port 80 - it is a HTTP trafic.
Somebody connects to your Web-server, write requests, gets data. Then your server shuts the connection down but your client doesn't understand this and continue sending requests.

It is not a security issue. It is possibly a misconfiguration of the server or bug in client.